# Is There A Heap Walker Equivalent For Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2010, memory, heap-memory

I am trying to run down out of memory nasty grams in a Visual Studio 2010 C# Web Application that does image to pdf conversions on demand...

Getting windows generic out of memory errors when doing 200k tif files... 
does not appear to be an addressable memory issue/limitation with the O/S ...

Visual Studio used to have a Heap Walker utility...

Is There A Heap Walker Equivalent For Visual Studio 2010?

What are some ways to run down out of memory errors with Visual Studio 2010 in debug mode or otherwise?

thanks in advance.